# Venmo not displaying with PayPal JS SDK Smart Buttons

Tags: paypal, venmo

I'm trying to implement PayPal and Venmo on my scratch Laravel project. The result should be like this:

[image]

However when I integrated it, it only shows these buttons:

[image]

Is there any way to display that Venmo button?

Here's the code, `&enable-funding=venmo` is included

```
     <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div id="smart-button-container" style="margin-top: 5em;">
                        <div >
                            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id={{env('APP_CLIENT_ID')}}&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>


        <script>
            function initPayPalButton() {
                paypal.Buttons({

                    style: {
                        shape: 'rect',
                        color: 'gold',
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        label: 'paypal',

                    },

                    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                        return actions.order.create({
                            purchase_units: [
                                {
                                    "amount":
                                        {
                                            "currency_code":"USD",
                                            "value":1
                                        }
                                }]
                        });
                    },

                    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                        
                        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                            
                            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

                            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                            
                            element.innerHTML = '';

                            element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                        
                        });

                    },

                    onError: function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
                }

                initPayPalButton();

        </script>
```

Reference: https://www.paypal.com/merchantapps/appcenter/acceptpayments/checkout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD`

You already are doing the right things with that on the SDK line.

However, Venmo will only appear to a US IP; for sandbox mode, you can simulate what a US buyer will see with `&buyer-country=US`

(Don't add buyer-country with a live client ID, as the buttons will not load -- only works for sandbox)

Comment: Thank you for this helpful information. It saves my time for exploring the integration.

Comment: I just used, VPN just to test the Venmo